# Diagnosing RCBO trip when heating elements turn off

Tags: circuit-protection, leakage-current

First up let me know if this should be over on home improvement or similar, I selected here as I thought it would be a better place to ask more technical questions.

Recently our sub-board was replaced to allow room for new circuits.

Since then we have had multiple trips on the oven circuit where only device is our electric oven. I believe previously the circuit was not protected by an RCD.

The breaker is a Clipsal MX9R3120 which is a 20A C curve RCBO with 30mA class A earth leakage

Unusually the trip only occurs when the oven reaches temperature on first heat up and the elements turn off.

Being a bit of a stats person we are setup with clamps on each of our circuits, that gets logged. From the graph I can see the oven pulled a little under 3.5kW (well under the 4800W for a 20A breaker) for about 7 minutes to heat up, at which point it beeps to indicate it has reached temperature and a few seconds latter the circuit trips. With the breaker reset the oven maintained temperature without tripping the circuit indefinitely.

[image: Power Consumption]

Since the time resolution on this data isn't very high to dig a little deeper I went to hook up a nicer current clamp to a scope that does DC to about a 1.5MHz.

It isn't easy for me to get a clamp into the sub-board but due to renovations going on I have easy access to the SDI wire that feeds the sub board and earths that run to the sub-board.

The below graph is our whole house consumption leading up to the trip. There isn't any obvious spikes that stand out that I would expect to trigger a thermal or magnetic trip.

[image: Zoomed out current]

Zoomed in on the point of turn off from the data.

[image]

I then captured the below plot with the clamp around the earth wires out of the panel, while not exactly the same as what the RCBO is measuring for leakage I would expect it to be fairly similar as the oven is installed in a wooden cabinet and doesn't touch any plumbing or otherwise grounded items.

From the plot I interpret that the oven has a leakage of >10, <15mA rms which is well under the trip threshold.

[image: Earth current]

So in summary

- Oven trips when reaching temperature and main elements turn off
- Current draw plot doesnt appear to show anything that should trip the breaker
- RCD plot doesnt appear to show anything that should trip the RCD protection in the breaker.

I am not sure where to proceed with testing.

To add a final confounding factor it appears that the oven does not trip if the oven temperature is set to a low temperature (say 150 degrees) and when the trip occurs it is only ever after reaching temperature, even if that temperature is set very high (>250 deg) with a corresponding longer heat up.

Comment: Could you repeat the clamp/scope analysis on the ground and neutral wires from the oven?  I suspect the culprit may be visible there.

Comment: Doing a trace with the clamp round the L & N wires (so you are looking at the same things as the RCD) would be the best plan.

You should also be aware that most oven elements are mineral insulated in an earthed metal tube.  If it hasn't been run for a while, moisture can penetrate and reduce the resistance, especially at elevated temperatures.  A couple of hours really hot (grill/clean setting) will normally drive the moisture out, and resolve issues.

Comment: I managed to get some space to get the clamps just around the L&N for just the oven circuit, of course the thing refused to trip despite having done so reliably for the last week... measured leakage crept up as temperature increased to 22mA rms @250deg. I also connected in a cheap RCD tester and was able to see that the trip value was pretty much 22mA so right on the edge. Per AS3000 this can be swapped for a non RCD breaker (would preffer not to), but I still don't understand why when the unit was tripping it would ALWAYS be just as the elements turn off after heatup regardless of set temp.

Answer (score 0):

In your earth current graph you have almost half a div of change, meaning the oven leaks about half of the rated ΔIn of your RCD. This allows the RCBO to operate, because with this current the operating time is indeterminate.

An RCBO has no requirements between 0.5 and 1.0 ΔIn. In summary:

- Below 0.5 ΔIn it may never trip.
- Between 0.5 and 1.0 ΔIn it is allowed to trip.
- Above 1.0 ΔIn it must trip within at least 300mS. *The time decreases with more ΔIn*.

This much leakage from an oven indicates a problem.

---

*This RCBO does not appear to have an indicator if it tripped due to differential current or overcurrent. Are these allowed in your region?*